# How to optionally pass a IClientSessionHandle using the C# MongoDB Driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, transactions, driver, optional-parameters

I use the repository pattern. My repository methods receive an optional IClientSessionHandle parameter which defaults to null. A part of each method prepares the filters/updates/etc., then a call is made. Since the session is optional, I have something like this:

```
if (sessionHandle != null)
    await Collection.InsertOneAsync(sessionHandle, myObject);
else
    await Collection.InsertOneAsync(myObject);
```

I suppose that always sending the session, null or not, wouldn't work, but I did not test it yet. Also, even if it would actually work, I would have no guarantee that this behavior wouldn't change in the future, as it's not part of the contract.

Is there a way to have a single call?

PS: The reason to have an optional IClientSessionHandle is to re-use the same repository methods, within a transaction or not.

Comment: i've had to use the [same pattern](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities/blob/bf9e998272e2a4ef5680195c829f2b46f0e218d9/MongoDB.Entities/DB.Save.cs#L46) as there's no other alternative than calling the appropriate overload depending on wether session is null or not.

Comment: JohnKnoop.MongoRepository provides an abstraction that automatically enlists with the current transaction. That means you don't have to bother with the separate calls. https://github.com/johnknoop/MongoRepository#transactions

Comment: @JohnKnoop I see your useful library automatically attaches to the current transaction. Doesn't the official `MongoDb.Driver` work in the same way? This article https://medium.com/c-sharp-progarmming/net-core-and-mongodb-unit-of-work-401d7483a25 seems to imply that it does, because it does not pass the session explicitly between starting it and commiting changes.

Comment: All Mongo driver methods have an overload that accepts a Session object. If you don't pass in a Session object, the operation will not be part of any transaction. I'm guessing the author of the linked article must have missed this.

Comment: you could try a ternary operator to see if that would work.

something like this:

await (sessionHandle != null ? Collection.InsertOneAsync(sessionHandle, myObject) : Collection.InsertOneAsync(myObject));

Answer (score 0):

a way is using optional parameters , for example :

```
public class Collection
{
    public Task InsertOneAsync(object myObject, object sessionHandle = null)
    {
        /*your code*/
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

now use its :

```
var collection = new Collection();
await collection.InsertOneAsync(myObject,sessionHandle);
```

---

another way is using factory class for example :

```
public interface ICollection
{
    Task InsertOneAsync(object myObject);
}
public static class CollectionFactory
{
    public static ICollection Factory(object sessionHandle)
    {
        switch (sessionHandle)
        {
            case null: return new SimpleCollection();
            default: return new SessionOrientedCollection(sessionHandle);
        }
    }
}

public class SimpleCollection : ICollection
{
    public virtual Task InsertOneAsync(object myObject)
    {
        /*your code*/
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
public class SessionOrientedCollection : SimpleCollection
{
    private readonly object sessionHandle;
    public SessionOrientedCollection(object sessionHandle)
    {
        this.sessionHandle = sessionHandle;
    }
    public override Task InsertOneAsync(object myObject)
    {
        base.InsertOneAsync(myObject);
        /*your code*/
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

now use its :

```
var collection = CollectionFactory.Factory(sessionHandle);
await collection.InsertOneAsync(myObject);
```